# Parallel execution using POM with PageFactory

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I started encountering problems when I use static objects reference for WebDriver and run the tests in parallel.

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

Hence I decided to use non-static object reference for the WebDriver.

```
private WebDriver driver;
```

Now when I use POM with Page Factory, my understanding is that everytime I create a Test I will have to be creating a new Object in the test class as shown below.

> /* Constructor in the Page Object class */

```
private WebDriver driver;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {           
         this.driver = driver; 
         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

> 2 testcases as shown below in the same class.

```
private LoginPage loginPage;    

@Test
public void testCase1() {
    loginPage = new LoginPage(getDriver());
    loginPage.sendkeys("sometext");
}

@Test
public void testCase2() {
    loginPage = new LoginPage(getDriver());
    loginPage.sendkeys("sometext");
}
```

My question here is a

1. Am I right in creating page object for every test cases?
2. Is there any way I can optimize this? Because One doubt I got is that non-static object reference may be getting overridden and causing problems in one of the methods if I run them in parallel.

Sorry if my query is naive. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to initialize it again. Also, initialize the pages in @BeforeTest rather than in test cases.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here i would like to give you example of Page object model. Hope you can relate this.

My Main test:

```
@Before
public void SelectBrowser(){
    driver = WebUtils.SelectBrowser(driver,"Chrome");
}


@Test
public void LoginToGmail() throws InterruptedException{
    //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//MAximize the Screen
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
//Go to Gmail Login Page
    SignInPage SignInPage = new SignInPage();
    WebUtils.GoToSignInPageForPropertyFile(driver, "URL");
//Click on Next
    SignInPage.ClickToLogin(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='next']"));
```

Now Supporting class:

GoToSignInPageForPropertyFile method will be in WebUtils 
Whatever i write in Webutils will be used by each page object class.

For e.g.

```
public class WebUtils {

    public static pageobject.SignInPage GoToSignInPageForPropertyFile(WebDriver driver, String URL) {   
        ReadFileData File = new ReadFileData();
        Properties Values = File.ReadFile();
    driver.get(Values.getProperty("URL"));
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageobject.SignInPage.class);
  }
}
```

Now the method ClickToLogin is defined under SignInPage class as:

```
 public class SignInPage {
 public EmailViewPage ClickToLogin(WebDriver driver, By by) {
    WebUtils.Click(driver, by);
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, EmailViewPage.class);
  }
}
```

Which will further be in Webutils

```
public class WebUtils {
    public static void Click(WebDriver driver, By by) {
        WebElement Element = driver.findElement(by);
        Element.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Do reply for further query. :-)

Comment: Kishan I am struggling when it comes to firefox object retention when it comes to parallel execution. Let's say if I am running testcases in 2 class file in parallel (by setting parallel="tests") and I am using beforeclass/beforetest while initializing firefox driver which is in a separate class, then if the testcases in classA is completed then it is quitting the driver (which I am aware why) and will not be available for ClassB. What I want is separate driver instance for each test class. How can make it possible and is it the right way? ........

Comment: The only other way I can think of is making the driver initialization to @BeforeMethod... But it will consume a lot of time closing and opening the browser. Please suggest.

Comment: What type of project it is? Maven ?

Comment: Yes Kishan, It's a maven project.

Comment: So if you are using a Framework let us say, Junit you can create a suite and include those classes in that suite and run that xml. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes I am doing the same. When I run those testcases sequentially then everything is fine. But if I run in parallel things starts getting messy as it seems that the webdriver reference variable may be getting overwritten with the new address. I get messages I could find the element or the window does not get closed. I am not experimenting on the running methods in parallel, but I am trying to run classes in parallel. As I said the only way I know is to use @beforeMethod and I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: The only thing now you can do is Share me the code so that ii can run that xml in debug mode to see with all classes. Please.